# Show notification in add-in using officeJS API

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I have implemented error message for excel add-in using fluent UI. If the text box is empty, then it will print message in the DOM. **For error message image is below**
[image: Error Message]

Now, this message is displaying in the React DOM. I want to display this message in the Excel anywhere. Like notification.
Is this possible that we can create a custom notification which will not render in the react dom. It will show the anywhere in the excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get access to the status bar or other notification areas of Excel with runtime code in the add-in. The only way to dynamically add a message to the Excel surface is to insert it into a cell of the worksheet.